# 2048: what are the possibilities?

Tags: combinatorics

i hope you have heard of the game $2048$, if not read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)). it goes like this:

> [it] is a single-player sliding block puzzle game by Italian web developer Gabriele Cirulli.  The game's objective is to slide numbered tiles on a grid to combine them to create a tile with the number 2048. [it] is played on a gray 4×4 grid, with numbered tiles that slide smoothly when a player moves them using the four arrow keys.[9] Every turn, a new tile will randomly appear in an empty spot on the board with a value of either 2 or 4. If two tiles of the same number collide while moving, they will merge into a tile with the total value of the two tiles that collided.
>                                                              -wikipedia

Anyway, now that you get it, i have a question: in chess, there are at most $10^{120}$ possible games. i am wondering this: has anyone calculated the number of possible $2048$ games, stopping at 2048?(because if we go to the end, then things will be impossibly large.)  then, if one cannot calculate it, could you compare the number of games of $2048$ to the number of games of chess $\left(10^{120}\right)$

and calculate the number as so:

1: the spawning of tiles is random (as in there are 2 tiles at the start, with a total of $960$ possibilities before move 1)

2:you stop at the move that gets $2048$

3:the grid is the normal $4\times 4$ (there are $5\times 5$, $6\times 6$, and so on variants)

4:there are at least 15 moves

Besides this, anything should go(if i missed something, could you edit it in?) and there might be the number floating around the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very crude, conservative estimate: 11 possibilities for each cell (including blank) to the power of 16 = 4.595E16. Way less than 1E120.

Comment: And because there are only four moves available at each turn, it's very feasiblew to make an AI that alpha-beta prunes the search space to efficiently play the game. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048/22389702#22389702) for example.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel but that's only in each. what about the number of different games total?